# get_posts and multiple categories

Tags: categories, get-posts

I have created a custom query in hopes of showing the top posts from some child categories. The query has a big flaw: some posts belong to two categories; but, even if they get marked in BOTH categories, they only appear in one.

For example, a post marked in both "Navigating Difference" and "Learning Exchanges" will only appear in "Navigating Difference".

I also wonder if there's an easier way to do this: can I just query for all child categories of a certain category?

The query is:

```
<?php
    $posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=3&offset=0&showposts=3&cat=21,22,23,26,31,32,349');
    foreach ($posts as $post) :
        start_wp();
?>
<?php
    static $count1 = 0;
    if ($count1 == "3") {
        break;
    } else {
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead as your loop query..

```
<?php
    query_posts( 'category_name=YOUR_CAT_NAME&showposts=15' );
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use [`get_term_children()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) to get the child category id from a specific parent category.